# BASH automatic answer when ftp prompted username and password

Tags: bash, ftp, homebrew, command-prompt

I'm writing a bash script and I need to use the ftp command on macOS (from brew) with the automatic response of the user and password when requested.

I did a lot of attempts and tests but no one worked

Comment: What have you tried so far ? How did it fail ? Please provide a code sample, as well as sample input, expected result and the error you received

Comment: You can try using [expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385206/shell-ftp-expect-to-intelligently-copy-files-from-local-to-ftp-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file named `~/.netrc`. Add these lines:

```
machine ftp.host.example.com
login yourUsername
password yourPassword
```

Give the file restricted permissions: `chmod 600 ~/.netrc`

Now you can `ftp ftp.host.example.com` without having to supply login credentials.

Check your `ftp` and `netrc` man pages.